# Refactoring in Python (extract new method in Eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse

I am trying to refactor some **Python 2.7** code into a new method in Eclipse.  After I use Eclipse's `Refactoring->Extract method` on the block marked by comments below, my image no longer shows up in the GUI:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, W, E, N, S, Label, Frame

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def myCallback():
    pass

root = Tk()

# start refactor method here

root.geometry('400x400')
runButton = Button(root, text="Run",bg='green',
    command=myCallback)
runButton.grid(row=2, column=0,
        padx=10, pady=10)
quitButton = Button(root, text="Quit",
command=root.quit)
quitButton.grid(row=2, column=1,
        padx=10, pady=10)

frame1 = Frame(width=200, height=200)
frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1,
        sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=10, pady=10)
image1 = Image.open("C:/Users/me/Pictures/house.jpg")
size = 64,64
image1.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1) 
label1 = Label(image=photo1) 
label1.grid(row=0, column=10, columnspan=1, rowspan=1,
        sticky=N+E, padx=10, pady=10)

# end refactor method here

root.mainloop()
```

Could someone explain why the image disappears and suggest a solution such that I can refactor without losing the image?

After refactor:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, W, E, N, S, Label, Frame

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def extractedMethod(root):
    root.geometry('400x400')
    runButton = Button(root, text="Run", bg='green', command=myCallback)
    runButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    quitButton = Button(root, text="Quit", 
    command=root.quit)
    quitButton.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    frame1 = Frame(width=200, height=200)
    frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=W + E + N + S, padx=10, pady=10)
    image1 = Image.open("C:/Users/me/Pictures/house.jpg")
    size = 64, 64
    image1.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    label1 = Label(image=photo1)
    label1.grid(row=0, column=10, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N + E, padx=10, pady=10)

def myCallback():
    pass

root = Tk()
extractedMethod(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could show what the code looks like before and after **Refactoring->Extract method**.

Comment: Edited post to show code after refactoring

Comment: Try putting the `def myCallback():` back ahead of the `def extractedMethod(root):`.

Comment: Martineau - didn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're releasing the `PhotoImage` object too early.

As [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) explain:

> You must keep a reference to the image object in your Python program, either by storing it in a global variable, or by attaching it to another object.
>
> Note: When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.
>
> To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object. A simple way to do this is to assign the image to a widget attribute, like this:

```
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

You might think that passing it as the `image` argument to the `Label` constructor would keep it alive. But it doesn't; the `Label` doesn't actually keep a reference to the `PhotoImage` object itself, it's only the actual label construction in the Tcl code that runs after `mainloop` starts that does so. (It's similar to a weak reference, but not an intentional or explicit one, if that helps.)

So, the quick and dirty solution is to either add this to the top of `extractedMethod`:

```
global photo1
```

… or add this right after the `label1 = Label(image=photo1)` line:

```
label1.photo = photo1
```

---

A better way to avoid this is to use an OO design instead of a flat procedural design, so you have some reasonable object to own all your references.

Even the trivial version, as shown in [these examples](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/%7Eniehaus/classes/448-s04/448-standard/simple_gui_examples/) will work:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        # put the code from extractedMethod here,
        # but prefix every local variable with self,
        # and do the same for myCallback.
    def myCallback(self):
        pass
```

But you're probably better off with a real OO design, where your objects actually represent something, as in [the official examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program):

```
class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
    def myCallback(self):
        pass
    def create_widgets(self):
        # put the code from extractedMethod here,
        # again prefixing things with self
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time on this answer!  I wasn't expecting such a robust reply.  This is exactly what I needed - not to just get the answer, but to be shown the right way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add one line to the beginning of the`extractedMethod()`:

```
def extractedMethod(root):
    global photo1  # added
    ...
```

The problem is that otherwise`photo1`is a local variable which is discarded as soon as the function returns, so references made to it within the function become invalid.

One might think that the`label1 = Label(image=photo1)`statement would have incremented its reference count and prevented this from happening, but it apparently doesn't work that way. I've seen this before and personally suspect it's due to a bug in`Tkinter`...

Comment: It's not really a bug in Tkinter, it's a documented design choice. Although I'd agree is a weird and not-very-pythonic design choice, it's still intentional. (Or at least it's a considered consequence of the intentional design choice to make Tkinter deal in mapping Python names to Tcl names, rather than values to values.)